# Как узнать координаты касания у компонента PhotoView?

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент PhotoView, который позволяет увеличивать (уменьшать) изображение.

Как получить координаты касания по этому изображению при обычном и увеличенном (уменьшенном) виде?

Пробовал установить слушателя:

```
iv = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
....................
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // координаты касания
    mX = event.getX();
    mY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            mCoords = "Coords: x = " + mX + ", y = " + mY;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            // ничего не делаем
            break;
    }
    Log.d("MyLog", "Coord: "+ mCoords);
    return true;
}
```

Но тогда изображение перестает увеличиваться (уменьшаться).

Comment: Попробуйте изменить `return true;` на `return super.onTouch(v, event);`

Comment: горит красным  "onTouch". Попробовал "return super.onTouchEvent(event);" происходит крах при касании.

Comment: Ну да, поторопился. Тогда вот так попробуйте: `return iv.getAttacher().onTouch(v, event);`. Хотя нет, тоже не будет работать. Сейчас ещё подумаю. Но скорее всего нужно будет наследоваться и переопределять некоторые методы.

Comment: горит красным "getAttacher"

Comment: А что за библиотека то у вас, не эта [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)?

Comment: Да, вроде эта. Только подключена не через gradle. Может подключил неправильно. А что, у вас работает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59972/discussion-between-eugeneek-and-kaaa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам подойдёт имеющийся в `PhotoView` [OnPhotoTapListener](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/OnPhotoTapListener.java). В нем вы получите `x` и `y` в виде процента от ширины и высоты изображения. Устанавливается так:

```
iv.setOnPhotoTapListener(new OnPhotoTapListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPhotoTap(ImageView view, float x, float y) {
        // делаете то что вам нужно
    }
});
```